# Get only TextBoxes from Grid C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want something like this

```
foreach (TextBox tb in mainGrid.Children)
            {
                tb.Text = "";
            }
```

But this gives me all Elements.
Thanks for help

Comment: It is winforms ?

Comment: Then maingrid.Children only contains text boxes or their derivatives, otherwise you’d have an invalidCastException..

Comment: Why do you want this? Grids display data, they don't hold it. You don't mention what grid this is or even the application type (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, ASP.NET, MVC, Core, Blazor?) but in all cases, grids don't hold the data

Comment: Are you trying to reset an editable grid? You could "empty" the data it binds to, or replace the data source with an "empty" one.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first application in WPF. Would have been smart to mention that. I tried the whole thing with panels before but had problems with the view

Comment: It's often a good idea to tag your post with the language (which you did) and project type. Also define the type of `mainGrid`.

Comment: Would be a good idea, actually. Is my first post so please understand. Next time I know but then there are no more excuses.

Answer (score -1):

I've done it with CheckBox, I let you check :

```
foreach(CheckBox x in this.GridEquipement.Children.Where(x=> x.GetType()==typeof(CheckBox)))
{
    x.IsVisible = true;         
}
```

Comment: Better: `Children.OfType<TextBox>()`